# defining sidebar table of contents in beamer

Tags: beamer, themes, slideshow

I am writing a default beamer style for my slide. I wanna to define a shading box in the left side of slides and inser the section titles vertically at it. but I don't know how is it possible!!! the sidebar can be similar to "Berkeley" theme sidebar but at a different color and right side
thanks all

[image: the section title on the left side]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[right]{Berkeley}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=red}

\begin{document}


\section{text}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

---

For themes which - unlike the image you show in your question - have a colour shaded background:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[right]{Marburg}

\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas right}[vertical shading][top=red,bottom=blue]

\begin{document}

\section{text}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Sam, but really this is not suitable for me. I am using the default theme currently. You are saying that use Berkeley theme. this makes my previous setting collapsed. Do you misunderstand my purpose?

Comment: @mohammadfazli You did not show a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and never mentioned which theme you use. If you have problems with combining your code with the Berkeley theme, please ask a clear question that demonstrates your problems.

Comment: when I use your code but by Marburg them as follows:
        \usetheme[right]{Marburg}

        \setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=red}

Comment: @mohammadfazli [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) ???

Comment: see the following post